# Linux distributions without selinux

Tags: linux, security, selinux

Are there linux distros without selinux portion  in kernel? Sorry if that's dumb question ;), but my distro (debian) has it and i see that it's in kernel on kernel.org so i was wondering if it's so popular that every distro has it or some delete this portion of kernel and use something else? If there are distros without this kernel part (and i mean totally deleted, not just disabled and waiting for being enabled on boot like in debian) could you give some examples?

Comment: for me it seems ubuntu ships the kernel with selinux



$ grep -i selinux /boot/config-2.6.24-23-generic
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_AVC_STATS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM_VALUE=0
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_CHECKREQPROT_VALUE=1
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DISABLE=y
# CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_ENABLE_SECMARK_DEFAULT is not set
# CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_POLICYDB_VERSION_MAX is not set

Comment: If it's not actually *enabled* by default, why do you care?

Comment: What do you have against selinux?

Comment: well, maybe i want to use something else. what *you* have against someone controlling his own machine and disabling 'security' features which he found to not be as effective as their authors claim? there are some vulnerabilities which are easier to exploit with selinux enabled.

Comment: I can't speak for Phil, but in my opinion, any utility that breaks much, much more than it fixes is a candidate for avoidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are concerned about which modules and features are compiled into your kernel, you should maintain your own kernel, compiled by you. Debian has a system named make_kpkg to facilitate this process. You can copy over a stable config from /boot to the new kernel source tree and load that into your custom build so you don't have to configure everything from scratch. Then you have complete freedom to manually scan through every single kernel configuration setting, including SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

while it is in the vanilla kernel i presume every distro ships the system with that part enabled.

You can only disable it or recompile your own kernel without it.

```
title SE-Linux Test System
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.4.20-selinux-2003040709 ro root=/dev/hda1 nousb selinux=0
        #initrd /boot/initrd-2.4.20-selinux-2003040709.img
```

Comment: that doesn't directly answer my question, but maybe recompiling kernel isn't that bad idea, +1

Comment: check you kernel config:

CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX=y

i presume this is the default for all teh major linux distros

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu and Suse don't come with it in the default kernel, as they use app armor instead. I believe Gentoo uses GRsecurity, so doesn't come with it by default either

Comment: hardened Gentoo,  uses SElinux, but normal Gentoo doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on [SE-Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux#Implementations) has a list of distros that use it.

Not being mentioned doesn't mean others don't, but I'd look with ones not on the list first :)

[Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/) is a good spot to watch for updates on current and new distros.

Answer (score 0):

Slackware Linux uses vanilla kernels.

Comment: selinux IS on vanilla kernels

Answer (score 0):

SELinux ships with Debian, but it's disabled by default. There is a lot you need to do to enable it, so I wouldn't worry.  The only reason it's there is because a lot of companies that use Debian on their servers require SELinux -- so Debian offers it as a choice, but doesn't force it on any of it's users.

Comment: yes, but it's still there. just 'disabled' but it's there.

Comment: So why not compile a vanilla kernel from kernel.org without SELinux?